# a generic way in C# to call any function and return its return value (if any)?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I'm trying to think of a nice way to call ANY type of function. void or return value,  no params or many. i need to time the execution of this function and wish to hide away all this from the client.  so i just want to give the client code a way to use my class to call any type of function, then my class will execute it and time it, then return back to the client.

the part i can't figure out is how to support any type of function.  delegates need a type.  func needs a return.   i want somethign generic that will make the client do minimal amount of work to setup the params, and minimal amount of work to get the return value (if any).

is this possible without reflection?  performance is very important here.

I can imagine client code looking like this:

```
Recorder r = new Recorder();
r.Params.Add(param);
r.Params.Add(param);

r.CallFunc([function]);

MyReturnType ret = (MyReturnType)r.returnValue;
```

does that seem doable?

Comment: Can you given an example usage (or desired usage)? Generally one wants to call a function/delegate with a particular number of arguments (possibly 0) and, if there is a result, do something with it ..

Comment: How are you going to know what values to pass for the parameters? You could probably do something with Lightweight Code Generation (aka DynamicMethod) and/or expression trees. But you're going to have to do something about those parameters; you have to pass something.

Comment: right, the client will have to do some work. they will have to set up the call with their params and do some more work with a return value if any.  this part there's no way around.  but building a generic enough class to handle this is what i can't figure out.

Comment: i added some sample client code that i imagine would be how it would work.

Comment: If you can never know what types will be used.. you're going to encounter a lot of boxing/unboxing during this process, which will hinder performance.

Answer (score 4):

There's a widely used way to wrap method calls:

```
public static class Recorder
{
  // overload for any method, that returns value
  public static T CallFunc(Func<T> func)
  {
    // other stuff here
    return func();
    // other stuff here
  }

  // overload for any method, that returns void
  public static CallFunc(Action action)
  {
    // other stuff here
    action();
    // other stuff here
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
Recorder.CallFunc(() => someObj.SomeMethod(param1, param2));
```

Comment: this looks like what i need.  so as i thought there's no ONE perfect way to do this, but having two ways that cover it all isn't bad either!

Answer (score 0):

You could just overload your method.

```
void MyMetaFunction(Action action);
void MyMetaFunction<T>(Action<T> action, T arg);
TResult MyMetaFunction<TResult>(Func<TResult> func);
TResult MyMetaFunction<TResult,TArg>(Func<TResult,TArg> func, TArg arg);
```

And so forth.  Of course, this does put some limit on the number of arguments you can support, but maybe that is still ok for you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your expectations and pseudocode, you can do something like this.

```
public void SomeMethod(params object[] objects) {
}

public void SomeMethod(out object returnValue, params object[] objects) {
}
```

This supports both any number, and any type of arguments, and can return a value or not return a value depending on the overload the client chooses. But I have to say, this *seems* like a really bad idea, and you will be responsible for handling *anything* that's passed in as an argument.